# How do I insert the double dagger symbol for transition state?

Tags: chemfig

I'd like to use the double dagger symbol of the transition state after a squared parentheses in chemfig. Here it is what I've managed to do:

[image: ddagger]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemleft[
\chemfig{Si(-[2]O(-[:120]))(-[:150]O(-[:210]))(-[6]O(-[:300]))(-[:30]O-[:-30]Si(-[2]O(-[:120]))(-[:240]O(-[6]))(-[:300]O(-[6]))(-OH))}
\chemright]
\ap{$\ddagger$}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

As you can see the symbol is not at the upper right corner of the parenthesis. How can I move it to the right position? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every compound in a scheme is typeset in a TikZ node. You can visually check the name of the corresponding node by inserting

```
\schemedebug{true}
```

In the example you posted it's `c1`. You can now access this node in a `tikzpicture` or with `chemfig`'s wrapper `\chemmove`.

In the following example I use `\transitionstatesymbol` provided by the `chemmacros` package instead of `\ddagger`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

% \schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
  \chemleft[
    \chemfig{
      Si(-[2]O(-[:120]))
        (-[:150]O(-[:210]))
        (-[6]O(-[:300]))
        (
          -[:30]O-[:-30]
          Si(-[2]O(-[:120]))
            (-[:240]O(-[6]))
            (-[:300]O(-[6]))
            (-OH)
        )
      }
  \chemright]
\schemestop
\chemmove{
  \node at (c1.north east) {\transitionstatesymbol} ;
}

\end{document}
```

[image]